# Need Help publishing a browser enabled InfoPath form to a Sharepoint 2007 Server

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, infopath

I’m trying to publish an InfoPath form to a SharePoint document library, and have the form be viewable in a web browser.

The problem is that in the InfoPath publishing wizard tells me that although the form is browser compatible, that it cannot be browser enabled because of one of the following:

- The Server is not running InfoPath forms services
- The necessary features are not available on the site collection
- The policy setting on the server does not allow a user to browser enable forms.

Well, I’ve verified that the SiteCollection has an active feature called “Office SharePoint Server Enterprise Site Collection features”, which includes Form Services, so I assume that the first two issues are not the cause

Also, I’ve verified in Central Admin that the Forms Services are configured to allow browser-compatible forms to be viewable in the web browser.  So the 3rd reason doesn’t seem to make sense either.

I've tried applying different Security levels to the form: Restricted/Domain/Full Trust, but that doesn't seem to have an effect.  I have been able to publish this form to a different SharePoint site, so I'm assuming that the issue is with the configuration of the SharePoint site, not the InfoPath form

Does anyone have any other ideas as to why this might not be working?

Thanks for any help you can provide!!

Answer (score 0):

Try testing the XSN file against the MOSS server by copying the file to the server itself (c:\temp for example) and running the following command:

```
c:\temp> stsadm -o verifyformtemplate -filename myform.xsn
```

The tool STSADM.EXE sits in `%programfiles%\common files\microsoft shared\web server extensions\12\bin` so add this to your `%PATH%`.

Post the answer back here if it still baffles you.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the recommendation from @x0n to check if directory has been allocated as usable, check the event viewer and see if anything is showing.

As a stupid but check item go to:

> Central Administration > Operations > Convert License Type

and ensure that you have the enterprise Client access listed.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in the Form Lib Advanced Setting section you have the Option "**Display as a Web page**" is set "**Opening browser-enabled documents**"